# Ошибка Emgu.CV, при создании фото с вебки

Tags: c#, bitmap, emgucv, emgu

Когда я пытаюсь создать фото но выдает ошибку:

> Camera.cs(18, 35): [CS1729] "Capture" не содержит конструктор, который принимает аргументы 0.

> Camera.cs(19, 36): [CS1061] "Capture" не содержит определения "QueryFrame", и не удалось найти доступный метод расширения "QueryFrame", принимающий тип "Capture" в качестве первого аргумента (возможно, пропущена директива using или ссылка на сборку).

Код:

```cs
using System;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;
using Emgu;
using Emgu.CV;
using Emgu.CV.Util;
using Emgu.Util;
using Emgu.CV.Structure;

using DirectShowLib;

namespace TelegramPc.Functions
{
    public class Camera
    {
        public static void WebcumPhoto()
        {
            VideoCapture capture = new VideoCapture();
            Bitmap image = capture.QueryFrame().Bitmap;
            image.Save("photo.png");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: У `new VideoCapture()` в скобочках что-то должно быть. Поставьте курсор, нажмите F12, посмотрите варианты.